# How do I install the required ABI (arm64-v8a) and build a Titanium app for the Nexus 9?

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

When I build for the Nexus 9 titanium CLI returns:

```
[ERROR] The device "Nexus 9" does not support the desired ABIs "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
[ERROR] Supported ABIs: arm64-v8a, arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi, armeabi-v7a,armeabi, arm64-v8a

You need to add at least one of the device's supported ABIs to the tiapp.xml

<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    <!-- snip -->
    <android>
        <abi>armeabi,armeabi-v7a,x86,arm64-v8a,arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi,armeabi-v7a,armeabi,arm64-v8a</abi>
    </android>
</ti:app>
```

Then, when I add that line to the tiapp.xml file the CLI prints out:

```
[ERROR] Invalid ABI "arm64-v8a"

Valid ABIs:
   armeabi
   armeabi-v7a
   x86
```

I have installed all the available System Images and when I run `android list targets` I can see:

```
id: 5 or "android-21"
Name: Android 5.0
...
API level: 21
...
Tag/ABIs : android-tv/armeabi-v7a, android-tv/x86, default/armeabi-v7a, default/x86, default/x86_64
```

Comment: Remove x86 from your target ABI.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean but tried a few variations of that and didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Your first error message does not show support for x86. Your second error message does not show support for arm64. Check your Application.mk and/or Android.mk files and make sure they are consistent with your tiapp.xml.

Comment: The Nexus 9 has a 64-bit arm cpu, which is not on your list of targets.

Comment: Thanks, aside from knowing its 64-bit arm, Im not familiar enough (at all) with Android development to follow up on your other comments. Thanks though.

Comment: I figured out a workaround rather than a direct solution to the question: compile the app for distribution (ie for Google Play) and then use "adb install" to get the APK on to the Nexus 9.

Comment: Good to hear. You should post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Nah :) Im still researching a proper answer to the question so that I can build directly (and quickly) to the device. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make a distribution build (e.g. --target dist-playstore)
2. Install the build directly to the device

   adb install -rds "App.apk"

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround that you can use is removing the check for this from the build process in your titanium SDK.  For version 3.4.1, this is lines 1372-1394 in the file android/cli/commands/_build.js

This will again allow you to build directly to the device.